# Connect NS3 node to a local blockchain

Tags: simulation, simulator, blockchain, ns-3

Imagine that you have a local bolckchain network where each node is a container created in the same OS. Are there any way to connect each node with an other node created in a NS3 simulation?

Answer (score 0):

it could be possible through the emulation framework through linux containers [here](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_Linux_Containers_to_set_up_virtual_networks),[here](https://github.com/buzz66boy/ns3-lxc/releases)